# How to center a table in Classic thesis LyX version

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I am using classic thesis for writing my thesis and while placing tables, the tables are aligning to the left. I want the table centered. I am attaching images of the LyX code and the output. Any help is appreciated.

Table placement:

[image]

LyX code:

[image]

Comment: as I neither use `classicthesis` nor Lyx: is `classicthesis` relevant in the context of this question (or answer)? I.e., would you center your table differently if a different class were used?

Comment: @NilsL I don't think so. The answer below helped me achieve the necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside the table float, right click, choose Paragraph settings, and set the Alignment to *Centered*.

Comment: What if all of the options other than "Paragraph's Default (Left)" are greyed out?

Comment: @dmh I have no idea why that would be the case, I'd suggest you ask a new question that includes a minimal working example (https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4488).

Comment: Thanks, Torbjørn, but I figured it out already. New to LyX and I didn't realize that my table wasn't wrapped in a float already.

@other users, if you have problems, try highlighting/selecting your table (not just the cells in your table!) and then clicking "Insert > Float > Table" or using the "Insert table float" button from the top menu.